# Do while loop doesnt work on big data file

Tags: vba, excel, while-loop, formatting

I have big data file on excel, the file has 6930 rows and 8 columns,
the 8 column has percents (0%, 4%, 16%, 18%, 19% and etc..)
I tried to do a macro that paint all the rows that the percent in them are bigger then 18%, and it doesn't work.

The file start from row 3, so rows 1 and 2 are empty

The macro:

```
Sub Test_4

Dim i As Long

Dim countErr As Long

countErr = 0

i = 2

Do While Cells(i, 1) = ""

If Cells(i, 8).Value > 0.18 And IsNumeric(Cells(i, 8)) Then

    Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 8)).Interior.ColorIndex = 3

    countErr = countErr + 1

 End If

    i = i + 1
Loop

If countErr > 0 Then

 Sheets("test").Select

    Range("E8").Select

    Selection.Interior.ColorIndex = 3

    Range("D8").Select

          Selection.FormulaR1C1 = countErr
    Else

    Sheets("test").Select

    Range("E8").Select

    Selection.Interior.ColorIndex = 4

    Sheets("test").Range("d8") = "0"

    End If


End Sub
```

Comment: look up conditional formatting. You don't need a macro for this.

Comment: @vba4all Is there an easy way to do the whole row though?

Comment: @Chrismas007 yea, with a formula

Comment: Your code only loops *until* column A has a value - is that intentional?

Comment: The code suppose to go to column 8, find precents that are bigger then 18%, and paint the whole row, and then give the number of red paints rows to a "test" sheet

Answer (score 1):

A `Do While` loop might be a bad idea if Column H ever has a blank value part way down, instead you could do this (This will add conditional formatting to each line):

Given this input:

[image]

```
Sub testit()

Dim LastRow As Long, CurRow As Long, countErr As Long

LastRow = Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Cells.FormatConditions.Delete

With Range("A3:H" & LastRow)
    .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=$H3>0.18"
    .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    .FormatConditions(1).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    .FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
End With

countErr = 0
Dim cel As Range
For Each cel In Sheets("NAME OF SHEET").Range("H3:H" & LastRow)
    If cel.Value > 0.18 Then
        countErr = countErr + 1
    End If
Next cel

MsgBox "There are " & countErr & " rows greater than 18%"

End Sub
```

Running the code gives:

[image]

[image]

**Error Testing:**

```
Sub ErrorTesting()
    Dim cel As Range, countErr As Long
    countErr = 0
    LastRow = Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For Each cel In Range("H3:H" & LastRow)
    On Error GoTo ErrHandle
        If Not IsNumeric(cel.Value) Then
            MsgBox cel.Address & " is the address of the non-numeric Cell"
        End If
        If cel.Value > 0.18 And IsNumeric(cel.Value) Then
            countErr = countErr + 1
        End If
    Next cel
ErrHandle:
    If Not cel Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox cel.Address & " is the address and " & cel.Value & " is the value of the Error Cell"
    End If
    MsgBox countErr
End Sub
```

Comment: i have 2007, and thanks for the screen shots, i did the for loop too but it doesnt work well in big data base the .value gives a debug and i dont understand why. thats the reason i tried with do  while

Comment: @LironAlexandra the `.Value` in my code gives error? Did you `Dim cel As Range`?

Comment: any other idea? i'm lost, cant find the reason why it wont work

Comment: Never mind you don't have enough rep to chat.  Check my edit to make sure you are defining the Sheet for the `For Each` loop.

Comment: @LironAlexandra What exactly is the run time error?

Comment: for some weird reason the .value doesnt work in big data, if i change the value to text it kinda work, but its much longer and it's weird. i change this: If Cells(i, 8).Value > 0.18 And IsNumeric(Cells(i, 8)) Then
to this:
If Cells(i, 8).Text > "18%" And IsNumeric(Cells(i, 8)) And Cells(i, 8).Text <> "0%" And Cells(i, 8).Text <> "1%" And Cells(i, 8).Text <> "2%" And Cells(i, 8).Text <> "3%" And Cells(i, 8).Text <> "4%" And Cells(i, 8).Text <> "5%" And Cells(i, 8).Text <> "6%" And Cells(i, 8).Text <> "7%" And Cells(i, 8).Text <> "8%" And Cells(i, 8).Text <> "9%" Then

Comment: @LironAlexandra Are your percentages stored as text?  You shouldn't have to use `.Text`

Comment: no they don't, they are numbers. because the value didnt work i tried with text

Comment: @LironAlexandra it is possible that somewhere in the data you have a text value instead of a percentage.  Try my ErrorTesting code and report back what it shows as the Value and Address of the cell when the error occurs.

Comment: No i checked they are percent, the error i get with the error testing is: 91 object variable or with block variable not set

Comment: @LironAlexandra I forgot do define `LastRow`.  Try just my ErrorTesting sub again.

Comment: run time error 1004: method range of object _global failed

Comment: @LironAlexandra OK, fixed my errortester.  Try one last time.

Comment: hi, sorry for the late respond, it says h3 isnt numeric (cause its the subject of the table, and h5409 isnt numeric (there is a function that gives me the percent and when it does the function on some of them its 0/number so it gives #DIV/0!

Comment: @LironAlexandra is H5409 the last cell?

Comment: @LironAlexandra Do you see how at the end of the code, there is a MsgBox which displays `countErr`?  Is that number correct?

Answer (score 0):

Try this **(updated for error count)**:

```
Sub test()
Count = 0
i = 2
While Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, 8))
If Cells(i, 8).Value > 0.18 Then
Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 8)).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
Count = Count + 1
End If
i = i + 1
Wend
//rows count bigger than 18% in worksheet "test"
Worksheets("test").Cells(1, 1).Value = "Rows count bigger than 18%"
Worksheets("test").Cells(1, 2).Value = Count
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, it does work, but the error count still doesnt, any idea why?

Comment: This one work perfectly but it doesnt count the errors (the red painted rows)